# In sqlite, what is the largest size of blob which could fit into one page?

Tags: sqlite

I use sqlite to imitate page management. Consider I have a table `pages(pageid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC, pagedata BLOB)`.

I split the original datas into segments of a fixed size near 4096B (aka the page size), and store each into a BLOB structure. I want to ensure that each BLOB is contained by one b-tree page. But I'm not sure how much bytes I could use exactly.

I read some documents, and find that the b-tree page itself consumes some bytes as a header, and the BLOB structure itself seems to require some extra bytes to store. But I'm not sure about the exact number.

Comment: Why does it matter if each BLOB is contained in a single b-tree page? Usually, each table in a SQLite database has its own page. Have you confirmed with tests that page overlap for your BLOB data is causing a bottleneck?

Comment: @MarkBenningfield No. I'm trying to understand the binary layout of Sqlite but failed. This page(`https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#record_format`) says "When the payload of a b-tree cell is too large for the b-tree page, the surplus is spilled onto overflow pages. Overflow pages form a linked list." So I think It'd better to avoid it.